# Passing any value to FileUpload.FileName using a button click

Tags: asp.net

Despite the firing of the method associated with a form and button click, my fileupload will not pass a value to a string, am I doing something obviously wrong (or just wrong in general)?

Do I need to attach a handler to the fileupload

Here is some sample source, note, it is the only code in the project, I have not made any definitions to the button or fileupload anywhere else:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button_Click()

        Dim FileUpload1 As New FileUpload()

        Dim X As String = FileUpload1.FileName

        Response.Write(X)

     End Sub

End Class
```

and the form:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb"    Inherits="Test.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" text="Submit"/>
  <%--  <input type="file" />--%>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

After trying FileUpload.HasFile, it appears as though not only can I not get the file name (described to me in the answer below), but the FileUpload.HasFile is nothing when a file is associated with it as well, is there any reason for this?

```
Protected Sub Button_Click()

    Dim FileUpload1 As New FileUpload()

    'Dim X As String = FileUpload1.FileName

    'Response.Write(X)

    If (FileUpload1.HasFile) Then
        ' Do Something
        ' SaveFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile)
    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the **path of the uploaded file** in the client's machine, that is not allowed for security reasons.
However you should be able to get **just the file name** using the `FileName` property.
I check the **file name** in my applications when i want to test the to see the filetype that is uploaded.

I do not think the following line is required in your  `Protected Sub Button_Click()` function:
`Dim FileUpload1 As New FileUpload()`

That must be creating a new instance causing it to show you an empty File Name.

If you just need the **file name** and **not the entire path** you could try the above.

**Edit:** Just saw the edit to your questions. The line I asked you to remove may be causing `HasFile` property to be empty as well.

Comment: This was the problem with passing the file to HasFile as well, as associated with my edit

Comment: Great! Are you able to see the file name as well?

Comment: Yes, but not fully qualified, as stated below, in any case, it returns something other than empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass/assign name asp:FileUpload, as it is converted to `input` type `file` it is not allowed due to security reason. As it could **breach the security of client machine** that is browsing the website. The only possibility to assign it a value is through user selection that is browsing and assigning the file by user from client (browser)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx

You can use [FileUpload.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx) method to save the selected file.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
```

Comment: So despite the fact that this technically answers the question as it was posed, what is the purpose of the FileUpload tag then? can I grab the file and save it locally or grab the file and upload it to a DB, and how do I reference it.

Comment: You can save the file to whatever filename you choose, but you can not see the original file path as it was located on the users pc. Due to said security reasons in the answer above.

Comment: So lets now say I want to save a file to a DB, I save the file upload to a directory from the fileupload, I reference that file name, then upload it to a database? Is there a way to just send it to a DB?

Comment: Are you selecting file from browser and getting path in filename?

Comment: You can get the file extension and Rename it using naming convention like Report_123.xls and then pass this naming convention value to your DB where you store the file name with ID 123 for record. You can reference it back when you want to edit it!